# Compounded regex expression to remove substring between a special character and a set of possible subsequent character in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I want to turn these

```
(book/livre), (manitoba), the (territories/des territoires), canada

(book/livre), (ontario), the territories/des territoires, canada

book/livre 1, alberta, the territories, canada
```

Into

```
(book), (manitoba), the (territories), canada

(book), (ontario), the territories, canada

book 1, alberta, the territories, canada
```

Meaning I want to remove everything between / and ) or ,

My python code is as follow:

```
self.df_census1901['LOC'] = self.df_census1901['LOC'].str.replace(r'/.*?\,', ',')
self.df_census1901['LOC'] = self.df_census1901['LOC'].str.replace(r'/.*?\)', ')')
```

which works for the first two examples. But how can I combine them into one expression, and incorporate the handling of the last example which is to remove everything between / and the (space) before some number followed by a comma.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `book, alberta, the territories, canada`? Why is the `1` still present?

Comment: No, that's intentional and depicting the last example. I need to retain the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/.*?(\)|(?: \d+)?,)
```

And replace with group 1, `r"\1"`

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"/.*?(\)|(?: \d+)?,)", r"\1", your_string)
```

The start of the regex is the same as yours. The trick in combining the three cases is to use `|` and the an optional group `(...)?`.

Dissecting this part: `(\)|(?: \d+)?,)`

This is a group containing the pattern `\)|(?: \d+)?,`, which matches either a single `)` or the pattern `(?: \d+)?,)`. `(?: \d+)?,)` matches a comma, optionally following a bunch of digits following a space.

Replacing by group 1 basically replaces the whole match with whatever is matched in the `\)|(?: \d+)?,` part. If a bracket is matched a bracket is used for the replacement. If `1,` is matched then `1,` is used for the replacement.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QuZLJ/1)